# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined message

Tags: javascript, split

I've bought this one specific bot script. i give it a list of games (game names can have numbers, : ) with a key related to each and every game. and in order to ask the bot to give me a specific key from the list. i type ( !give [Game name] ). the bot checks the txt file and gives me the corresponded key to that game

For an example.

> Counter-Strike: Global Offensive ( 11111-11111-11111 )
>     Left For Dead 2 ( 22222-22222-22222 )
>     Half Life ( 33333-33333-33333 )

The issue here is :

When i type `!give Counter-Strike: Global Offensive` or `!give Left For Dead 2`
The bot crashes. But if type `!give Half Life` it will actually work and give me the key ( 33333-33333-33333 )

I checked the error log and I went to look for the line that's causing a problem; and I found this:

Error log :

> C:\Users\xxx\bot.js:1199
>                   var keys = data.split("\n");
>                                   ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
>       at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Users\xxx\bot.js:1199:19)
>       at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:422:13)`

this is the code refered to :

```
var sent = false;
files.forEach(function(file) {
      if (file.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")) {
        if (fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8").toLowerCase().split("\n")[0].trim() === titledab.trim()) {
          fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(error, data) {
                if (error) {
                  client.chatMessage(senderID.toString(), "An error occurred, sorry about that.");
                  return;
                }

                if (data == '' || data.split("\n").length <= 1) {
                  client.chatMessage(senderID.toString(), "No keys for that title right now.");
                  return;
                }
```

I'm not good at all when it comes to these things. Someone told me that the issue is also with toLowerCase as it doesnt work with numbers. please tell me whats wrong and whats the proper solution?

Comment: This flow is not optimal: you open and read the whole file once in sync mode to check something, then open the file again in async mode and do some work. Just open it once in async mode and do your logic there.

Comment: i would be lying if i said that i understood what you have just said...
I mean. all i know is that split("\n") should be split("[\\r\\n]+") and thats about it

Comment: Ok, I'll rephrase. You first have the guard `if (fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8").toLowerCase()` and then _inside_ that, you have another `fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(error, data) {`. What this does is open the whole file, read it once just to check something, then close it. Then if the `if` is true, it opens the same file again and reads it again. You can combine those two operations. I'll write up an answer if I have a moment this afternoon.

Comment: I salute you for trying to explain it! Looking forward to it!